# How to remove the top line of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift

How to remove the first line after the search bar?(see pic)
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is that you can't. The built-in cell dividers are either drawn everywhere, including above the top cell and below the last cell, or not at all.

The long answer is that you have to turn off cell dividers and add one-point lines at the top and bottom of your custom cells and then add code in your table view's cellForRow(at:) function that shows and hides the lines based on the cell's position in the table view. It's awful, horrible, fussy code to write, but I don't know of any other solution.

Comment: Come on man, there are like, a million duplicates of this: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+remove+the+top+line+of+UITableView